# How to find out the date of last importing data to my table in sql

Tags: sql

I  importe data from excel file to a specific table in sql every month ,
I want to find the exact date of last importing . How can i do that?

Comment: Please add tag of your specific DBMS product. This feature is absent by default but some engines may provide it via metadata dictionary or similar.

Comment: Do you log *import date* as well? If not, consider doing that and you'll have the answer right in front of you.

Comment: It is microsoft sql server @astentx